# Weka - Logistic regression - Interpreting results

Tags: binary, weka, regression, logistics

I am using Weka to perform a logistic regression using training data where a binary outcome is known. It performs reasonably well, categorizing approximately 80% of instances correctly. I also have a data set using current data where the outcome is unknown. When I run the model using the current data and output predictions, it classifies each instance as either Yes or No and provides an error and probability distribution term (where error + probability distribution = 1). I am having trouble understanding these results. Can someone help me with how I am supposed to interpret them? I have noticed that the model only guesses Yes when the probability distribution is below 0.5. Does that mean that I should read this as a 1-probability distribution that the outcome is yes?

Answer (score 1):

The class probabilites always have to sum up to 1. If you had P(Yes)=40% and P(No)=20% and *Yes* and *No* are the only classes, what would the missing 40% be?

Also, if the result says P(Yes)=60% and P(No)=40% and you were to give a prediction, not a probability, the obviously rational choice would be *Yes*, because it has the highest probability of all options. This is the [Bayes optimal decision rule](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~vb198/compilation/node3.html). (Thanks to *larsmans*)

In binary classification problems, this is the same as choosing the answer with P>50%.

Without knowing what the actual output that you get looks like, it indeed seems as if the probability you get is P(No)

Comment: +1. FWIW, picking the class with the highest probability (or >½ in the binary case) is called the [Bayes optimal decision rule](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~vb198/compilation/node3.html).